# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-stringutils

I am writing map reduce program to compare two files.When I run the program it throws following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
at org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory.getName(MutableMetricsFactory.java:119)
```

MY pom file.

```
 <dependencies>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
<version>0.20.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
<version>0.23.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <type>jar</type>
    <version>15.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
<version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
 <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
 <version>3.3</version>
  </dependency>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
 <version>1.1.1</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

As the error message `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils` tells you, you need to add commons-lang as a dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

You have added `commons-lang3` which has also a class StringUtils, but with the package name `org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils`.

Comment: Yeah that error is resolved.But right now I am getting following error.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.VerifyError: class org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$CompleteRequestProto overrides final method getUnknownFields.()Lcom/google/protobuf/UnknownFieldSet;

Comment: @ArunKumar Looks like you have incompatible jar's in the classpath.